# Formula for pattern in excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a question regarding excel.

Given:

```
Col 1      Col 2
A             A
B             A
C             A
D             A
E             B
F             B
G             B
H             B
```

I want to copy the values in column 1 in Col 2 so that each value repeats itself  4 times as  shown. I have been looking at a formula that will help me do this efficiently without having to copy and paste all the time. Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: I'm commenting this because I dint have the time to properly write it up or test, but you could check if the above 4 cells are all the same letter, and if they are pull the value one down from that one, else pull the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data in column **A** , in **B1** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0),0)
```

and copy down

**EDIT#1**:

To start in row #2, in **B2** enter:

```
=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP((ROW()+3)/4,0),0)
```

and copy down

Comment: Hi, This seems to be working, but What can I do if I want to start in row 2? I tried =INDEX(A2:A14,ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0),0), its not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your values start in A2, enter this in B2 and fill down

```
 =OFFSET(A$2,FLOOR((ROW()-ROW(B$2)/4,1),0)
```